# android issue while removing item from listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with each row containing some text and a delete button.
When delete button is pressed the row has to be deleted.

I am using a base adapter and there is a global list the item of which will be displayed.

Please see my adpater code below

```
    public class JobCartListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public JobCartListAdapter( Context mContext) {
        super();

        this.mContext = mContext;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    Context mContext;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return JobsManager.JobsCartList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_cart_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.delete = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("Remove from" , "" + position);
                    JobsManager.JobsCartList.remove(position)   ;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text1.setText(JobsManager.JobsCartList.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        ImageButton delete;
    }
}
```

the issue i am facing is :

1. when i press delet for the firstime , the position within the list is correct and the item is deleted and list is getting refreshed
2. when i click again on a row in the refreshed list , the corresponding position passed to getview is not right . So its leading to an index out of bound exception as that position is used as index for list . I checked my list and it is correctly updated on add and remove .
   Its the problem with list adapter. After refresh of the list with call of notifystatechanged, when a row is clicked, the postion of the row returned is not correct.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to remove the View just remove the relates object by `adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));`
it will remove the specified object from list & call the the method `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: can u pls explain what this "adapter" actually means . i dont see any such function for Base adapter

Comment: sorry preetha my mistake actually your converview getting reused & the onclicklistener of delete is holding the old position so do one thing set position as tag to delete button like `delete.setTag(position+"");` & in click listener get that tag of button & do delete also in getview if converview is not null then extract delete button from converView & set tag again

Comment: yes, the issue was due to reusing converview. I changed that to not to reuse as that seemed easier. Thanks a lot.